# JSON.parse is not working on iPad safari

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ipad

I am doing one ajax call and in `success` function I am using `JSON.Parse` function.But the problem is that `JSON.parse` function is working everywhere except in **iPad-Safari Browser**(*iPad Version~7.0.6*).In iPad Safari , my code after the line where I used `JSON.Parse` does not seems to be executed .I tried `alert` with some message under the line `JSON.Parse` but had no luck.Can we find a work around of this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the **SCRIPT** I am running:

```
var obj = JSON.parse($('#divWOListForFE').html());
alert('hello'); //this alert doesnt execute on iPadSafari
$('#divWOListForFE').html('');
BindWorkOrderGrid(obj, 1, 10);
```

The *value* of  `$('#divWOListForFE').html()` is below

```
"[{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6806,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":242,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Mfsi - Mindi M1","StartTime":"10/1/2014 8:00:00 AM"},{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6807,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":243,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Mfsi - Murli Mindi","StartTime":"8/1/2014 8:00:00 AM"},{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6808,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":244,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"adding a new description for this field user.","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Mindi, Shiv","StartTime":"10/2/2014 8:00:00 AM"},{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6808,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":244,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"adding a new description for this field user.","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Mindi, Shiv","StartTime":"10/2/2014 8:00:00 AM"},{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6809,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":245,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Sudhansu-Dummy test","StartTime":"10/5/2014 1:00:00 PM"},{"Pk_WorkOrderId":6809,"Fk_CompanyId":null,"Fk_CreatedByUserId":null,"Fk_ProposalId":null,"Fk_InvoiceId":null,"OrderNo":245,"Fk_SiteAddressId":null,"Fk_CustomerId":null,"Fk_GanttItemId":null,"AppointmentDateTime":null,"TimestampCreated":null,"CreationDate":null,"TimestampModified":null,"Description":"","EquipmentNeeded":null,"SpecialInstructions":null,"WorkOrderType":"Contract","JobType":null,"HourlyRate":null,"CompletionStatus":null,"TotalEstHrs":null,"TotalActualHrs":null,"WorkToBePerformed":null,"BIllingStatus":null,"OkToBill":null,"WorkOrderStatus":"Scheduled","IsDeleted":false,"IsProposalSort":null,"TotalRecords":6,"IsUserCreator":1,"CreatedBy":"Mndi,Murali","CustomerName":"Sudhansu-Dummy test","StartTime":"10/5/2014 1:00:00 PM"}]"
```

Comment: Please post some code!

Comment: will be able to use your code here..

Comment: Or try by using jquery.ParseJSON()

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam  : I added my code. please see.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The JSON data is valid but when strings that look like Dates or Strings are present within a HTML node both the iPad and iPhone will automatically create clickable links. So basically your JSON is getting mangled when you put it into a standard HTML DOM node.

JS fiddle that shows it working on Desktop:
http://jsfiddle.net/8wptohs0/1/

This same JS fiddle does not work on iPhone simulator (there was no alert):  (If you look closely you can see the simulator has turned the `StartDate` field data into blue clickable links)
[image: iPhone JSON parse error]

If I remove the `StartTime` property data, it works on the desktop and the iPhone
http://jsfiddle.net/8wptohs0/2/

[image: JSON.parse working on iPhone]

To fix this, there are some meta tags that should do the trick - you may have to experiment on which ones work for you.

`<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="date=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="address=no">`

However it is worth saying that when inserting serve side data into javascript a `data-` attribute or inline JS is a more commonly used method - for exactly these kind of reasons.

Comment: Thanku so much for this amazing explanation:)

but the meta tag you told above did not work.Instead of this I tried this meta tag <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> and it works. Can you tell me why this happend?

Comment: I've added your answer in there - there are different types of data you can tell apple not to automatically make into links. It looks like `telephone=no` is what you need to do to make it stop formatting links that looks like dates. This seems weird but I've confirmed it here: http://jsfiddle.net/8wptohs0/5/  (see meta tags on CSS panel)

Comment: I checked your fiddle in iPad after removing <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"> from the css panel. It did not work. while only including this telephone meta tag,It started working.
anyways your answer was really helpful to me.Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

For me this the meta tag which worked for me inside head section.

```
<head>
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
</head>
```